Configuring the trigger Path parameters while promoting my pipeline to higher environment
I have configured triggers in my development environment to run adf pipelines in an event driven manner. Currently my triggers are pointing to a specific folder which contains environment tag which is 'DEV/Upload/Process/samplefile.xlsx'. When I try to promote these pipelines to production I want the tag to be updated to 'QA/Upload/Process/samplefile.xlsx' which I am not able to do it using global parameters. Currently I am manually changing the trigger path in production once the deployment is completed which is not an efficient way to do things in production. The deployment is happening via arm template deployment using Github actions.

Can you provide your trigger configurations for better understanding of the issue?
